# NextJS project compilation fails with JSEncrypt

Tags: next.js, encryption-asymmetric, jsencrypt

I've installed JSEncrypt npm package for asymmetric encryption.
But when I  run the project I get the below error

**Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined**

I even tried to dynamically load the JSEncrypt.min.js file in the project.

Can some one help resolving this?

Comment: Since Next.js is built on top of Node.js have a look here: https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/147

Comment: Can you show how you're using JSEncrypt in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic import provided by Next.js. Import JSEncrypt only when you need to use it instead of importing it at the top of a module.
The code below works for me.

```
async function decrypt() {
  const JSEncrypt = (await import('jsencrypt')).default
  var encryptor = new JSEncrypt()
  /* DO SOMETHING */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `window` is not defined while Server Side Rendering.
Importing the component (where you are including JSEncrypt) with `next/dynamic` and SSR set to false should fix the issue.
Ex.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const ComponentWithJSEncrypt = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/myComponent'), // path of your component
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Comment: I tried it. Doesn't help